# Algorithm for getting all 2D necklaces

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, necklace-and-bracelets, lyndon-words

Let's assume that we work in the finite field of two elements, $\{0, 1\}$.
We want for example to construct all the necklaces of length $N = 3$.
Thus, from the full set of ALL PERMUTATIONS (edit:to be clear)
$$\{0, 0, 0\}, \{0, 0, 1\}, \{0, 1, 0\}, \{0, 1, 1\}, \{1, 0, 0\}, \{1, 0, 1\}, \{1, 1, 0\}, \{1, 1, 1\}$$
we get the elements (NECKLACES:edited to be clear)
$$\{0, 0, 0\}, \{0, 0, 1\}, \{0, 1, 1\}, \{1, 1, 1\}.$$

One efficient way (compared to the brute force method) to get all necklaces is to use Savage's algorithm or its later versions.

What would be the way/algorithm to get all necklaces in $2$D?
We assume that the matrix is periodic across the x- and y- dimension.
Say we have $(N_x, N_y) = (3, 3)$, then the matrices
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
are equivalent, while the matrices
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
are not.

What would be the algorithm for getting the necklaces for a given $(N_x, N_y)$?

Comment: You can use Burnside's lemma and use group action of $D_x$ and $D_y$ on the set of necklaces.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140802/discussion-on-question-by-konstantinos-sfairopoulos-algorithm-for-getting-all-2d).